# How to change the content type of view from while returninng it

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel I know how to send a parameter in view but, how can i return set the `content type` for the page that is being returned from the controller ?

I tried to do it after the page generates,, but i want do that in controller because i want to use `phpexcel` operations..

i tried to search in many places but all deals only after the page is rendered.

So, My Question is How can i do that in controller itself ?

Comment: did you add an exit(); in the end after the save operation is done..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by

```
return response()->view('hello')->header('Content-Type', $type);
```

See more about it here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses

To pass any messages in the view add this next you call your view

```
->with('message', 'Your Message here');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the content type over the `header()` function of a response object. There's even an [example in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#basic-responses) on how to do that (scroll down to *Sending A View In A Response*)

```
return response()->view('hello')->header('Content-Type', $type);
```

Answer (score 0):

*laravel 5.0:*

```
return response()->view('hello')->header('Content-Type', $type);
```

*laravel 4.0:*

```
return Response::view('hello')->header('Content-Type', $type);
```

Comment: depends on what you want send.

Comment: can you give an example of what you are sending?